# Organizer of what?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I gave [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/404690/using-pcie-and-onboard-together) an overhaul in grammar and got both the Editor and the Organizer badges. I'm totally cool with this myself, I think I deserved the two badges, but I didn't do anything with the tag except clicking on it. The description of the Organizer badge is *"First retag"*, so isn't this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The organizer badge is awarded for your first retag, and you removed two tags from the post, so this was considered  a retag.

Comment: I didn't notice myself doing that and have no memory of it. Maybe I should take this question to a doctor instead. Sorry for the stupid question :P

Comment: @Skya [See the revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/404690/revisions), you removed two tags.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks, I didn't notice the history feature! I removed the tags by accident and will put them back again =D

Comment: @skya to access it, click the "edited" link below a post. See e.g. Nhinkle's edit to your q above.